# I read a code somewhere which assigned Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) and then setSupportActionBar(toolbar); What is happening here?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

Can anyone explain the snippet given below. What happens with the following:
1.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
2.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

The snippet of code is:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Comments");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: We need more context and details here.

Answer (score 0):

you can reach the app bar(action bar) via the toolbar . you make a toolbar and design it however you like then change the style of app to no action bar, then in code set you toolbar as actionbar. then your design toolbar will be the app bar

Answer (score 0):

Just an example.
Use an Activity with this theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

and this layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then just use:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

It is the result. Just an empty `Toolbar`.

[image]

Add the [`setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity#setSupportActionBar(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar))

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
}
```

[image]

**This method sets the toolbar as the app bar for the activity**

Now add [`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBar#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean))

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

}

[image]

**This method set whether home should be displayed as an "up" affordance**